# How to make Criteria OR query with two different tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I want to make a criteria query that I have to compare two tables. I mean, I have one field, for example, "NAME", and I want to found all the entries that have "NAME en 2 tables; "Owners" and "Sellers", I made this, but I don't know how to add the second table to the criteria instructions:

```
 DetachedCriteria subqueryDocumentoIdentificativo = DetachedCriteria.forClass(
                Owner.class, "rrepr");
        subqueryDocumentoIdentificativo.setProjection(Projections.property("owner"));
        subqueryDocumentoIdentificativo.createAlias("owners", "own");
        subqueryDocumentoIdentificativo.createAlias("own.person", "person");
        subqueryDocumentoIdentificativo.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions
                .isNotNull("person.cdName"), Restrictions
                .isNotNull(???????)));
        query.addHibernateCriterion(Subqueries.exists(subqueryDocumentoIdentificativo));
```

I also try with this other option:

```
if(this.getFiltros().get("cdDocumentoIdentificativo") != null
            && !((String) this.getFiltros().get("cdDocumentoIdentificativo")).isEmpty()) {
        
        query.addHibernateCriterion(Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.eq("owner.own.person.cdDocumentoIdentificativo", "cdDocumentoIdentificativo"),
                Restrictions.eq("sellers.sell.person.cdDocumentoIdentificativo","cdDocumentoIdentificativo")));
       
    }
```

No one works...

How can I do it? I don't know if this is the correct way to do it or not, because it's my first attempt with Criteria. So, if you know another way to do it, it could be fine too.

Comment: Try using JPA Criteria instead. The legacy Hibernate Criteria API was deprecated in 5 and removed in 6, so beware that your code will break when you update Hibernate.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov hi! thanks for your advice, can you help me in what I want to do, please? I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: both tables have any relation between them?